# numberformatexception facebook ads

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-audience-network

I recently added facebook ads to my app. Till yesterday it was working fine but from today the app is crashing because of facebook ads.The stack trace is :

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "false"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:525)
at com.facebook.ads.internal.h.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.ads.internal.h.h(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.ads.internal.j.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.ads.internal.j.a$b.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at          com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

please help me solve this error